# Exim: match recipient address against certain regex and conditional email delivery

Tags: exim, regex, aliases

I need to allow my customers to use e-mails in format of **4ca2bc00-6789-4161-bae7-c11c5b91454e@example.com**, where the username part is sort of UUID. Those emails should be delivered to certain (single) e-mail address (for example - **inbound@example.com**) to be processed later on, and the recipient address is used to distinguish among users. Generally, it's not possible to write those UUIDs into the `/etc/mail/aliases` because there's no way to know the list of those UUIDs in advance.

How can I configure routers for system aliases or local users to accept those e-mail addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
begin routers
guids:
  driver    = redirect
  senders   = \N^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}@example\.com$\N
  data      = inbound@example.com
  pipe_transport  = address_pipe
. . . . . .
```

That router catch all messages with localpart matched by regexp and redirect them to the single address.

Comment: This answer could be improved with some explanation of what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record

```
begin routers
....
regexalias:
  driver = redirect
  data = ${lookup{$local_part}wildlsearch{/etc/aliases.wildcard}}
```

/etc/aliases.wildcard

```
^[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}        user
```

that allows to have more *flexible* patterns that do not require exim restart

Comment: And what if `$localpart` is not matched by regexps in the file? Huh?

Comment: then the email is rejected. Exactly what I need.

Comment: So you want that router be placed just before rejector? And all legal addresses are processed above?

Comment: then it will be caught by a next router.

Comment: Nope. After that router any not matched message become the message with no recipients

Comment: I would agree if that wouldn't work for me. But it does resolve the regular aliases through the system aliases route that appears after this route.